# Mocking the behaviour of operators in Moq C#

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, moq-3

Hope your well.

I am in the process of creating some tests using Moq in C#. One of the objects I am Mocking has overridden ==, > and < operators.

Does anyone know if its possible, and if so how to... configure a Mock object to replicate this. The reason I ask is that I am trying to inject a mocked stub as some legacy code I have been given that has deep and dirty dependencies.

Your time is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you override such operations you should also provide theirs named equivalents too. If you rework yours code in such way it will be easier to mock it.

```
public static bool operator ==(SomeType a, SomeType b)
{
    return a.Equals(b);
}

public virtual bool Equals(SomeType b)
{
   // yours logic here
   return base.Equals(b)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. In this instance I need to avoid touching the existing code at all which makes life very difficult. This is for business reasons as the code is safety related and so validated etc. EDIT: The original developer has supplied those versions in this exa mple I have found, thanks though normally that would be a very good answer.

Comment: Fortunatly looking into it that is how the original object is written so in this instance this will work. Thanks for your time.