# How to mock an operator overloading with NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I'm testing a class `ClassA` that takes an instance of a class `ClassB` in its constructor. In my test of `ClassA`, I mock `ClassB` with `NSubstitue`. However, `ClassB` overload the `*` operator. How can I set the `Result` of the `*` operation for my `ClassB` mockup?

Comment: Can you please add the two classes to the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898447/mocking-the-behaviour-of-operators-in-moq-c-sharp

Comment: Don't mock it !